# LSSharedFileListItemResolve throws: "URLs with the type "nwnode:" are not supported"

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am trying to iterate my favorite items (left sidebar) and the following code throws an error:

```
LSSharedFileListRef favoriteItems = LSSharedFileListCreate(NULL, kLSSharedFileListFavoriteItems, NULL);
LSSharedFileListItemRef itemRef = (__bridge LSSharedFileListItemRef)[favoriteItemsArray objectAtIndex:i];
if (LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, 0, (CFURLRef*) &url, NULL) == noErr)
{ ... }
```

The "LSSharedFileListItemResolve" throws an alert whenever it iterates a link to "AirDrop" folder.:

"There was a problem connecting to the server. URLs with the type "nwnode:" are not supported"

The code runs smoothly for all the other items.

Any ideas how to avoid this alert?

Thanks, 
Nili

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can control this using the inFlags argument:

```
LSSharedFileListItemResolve(itemRef, kLSSharedFileListNoUserInteraction | kLSSharedFileListDoNotMountVolumes, &urlRef, NULL)
```